# I need to remote desktop into 100s of VMs created in Azure

Tags: azure, remote-desktop, azure-virtual-machine

I will be creating 100s of Virtual Machines in the Azure, which I will use them for execution of my UI test case. Challenge here is I Need to have a active desktop for running the Tests. Currently at on promise I download Microsoft Remote desktop manager and make connections to 20-30 machines from each RDP session and hence able to keep desktop active for 100s of VMs.

In Azure I have observed that it downloads 1 rdp file for each VM. So my question now is what is the best way to remote desktop into 100s of VMs running in azure ?. Are there any other ways to keep desktop active and logged in without using the RDP manager  ?

Comment: This is off-topic for StackOverflow, as it's not programming-related. And honestly, how you manage your network and remote desktop collection is up to you. Have you looked at the rdp files that come down? Perhaps the tool you're using can import all of them? Regardless: Probably better to ask on something like SuperUser.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are simply trying to have the VMs log in as a user when it boots, you can achieve that by setting registry keys through the custom script extension.  Write a powershell script that sets the auto-logon registry keys and run it via the custom script extension.  The powershell script may need to reboot the VM at the end to get it to log in the first time.

Here is a custom script extension example:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-vm-custom-script-windows

Here is info on the registry keys for automatically logging in on startup:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/324737

You also probably want to set the screen resolution to something reasonable:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj603036(v=wps.630).aspx

Comment: The OP didn't ask anything about automatic logins. They asked about managing a large quantity of RDP connections.

Comment: @DavidMakogon read the last sentence again:
Are there any other ways to keep desktop active and logged in without using the RDP manager ?